# Android app crashes when I run it on API 30 Android Virtual Machine

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, text-to-speech

I am trying to make something that converts the text i write into EditText to speech when i press button01.
It works fine on the virtual machine with Android API 23, but it crashes and makes a NullPointerException and crashes on the virtual machine with Android API 30. Here's the code:

```
public MainActivity() {
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button01);
    final TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1) ;
    textView1.setText("\n");

    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status != ERROR) {
                // 언어를 선택한다.
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
            } else {
                textView1.setText("TTS 작업에 오류가 생기거나 지원되지 않는 언어입니다.");
                tts.speak("TTS 작업에 오류가 생기거나 지원되지 않는 언어입니다.", TextToSpeech.STOPPED, null);
            }
        }
    });

    button01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // editText에 있는 문장을 읽는다.
            tts.speak(editText.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // TTS 객체가 남아있다면 실행을 중지하고 메모리에서 제거한다.
    if(tts != null){
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
        tts = null;
    }
}
```

}
When i view Logcat, it showes this:

```
2020-07-09 02:10:56.036 7700-7700/com.example.myapplication2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication2, PID: 7700
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication2/com.example.myapplication2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.speak(java.lang.String, int, java.util.HashMap)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.speak(java.lang.String, int, java.util.HashMap)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.myapplication2.MainActivity$1.onInit(MainActivity.java:42)
    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.dispatchOnInit(TextToSpeech.java:836)
    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.initTts(TextToSpeech.java:814)
    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:745)
    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:724)
    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:708)
    at com.example.myapplication2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7995)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7979)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: On API 30, does it crash only when you push the button?  Or before you press it? (Also, you should look at your code inside onInit() ... because it does not make sense if you examine it closely -- you are saying, "If the tts does not initialize, then speak.")

Comment: when I try to open the app, it crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening in the else part in `onInit` of your listener. When there was an error in initializing the `TextToSpeech` instance, `onInit` will be called with `ERROR` as input while `tts` is not yet initialized and is `null`.

It may happen when your device doesn't support text to speech or the engine is missing necessary data.

Don't call anything on `tts` in case of an error. (There was an error in initializing text to speech. So, how can it speak your text?!)

Comment: your welcome. please mark it as answer if you've found it working.

Answer (score 0):

Apps targeting Android 11 that use text-to-speech should declare `TextToSpeech.Engine.INTENT_ACTION_TTS_SERVICE` in the queries elements of their manifest:

```xml
<queries>
   ...
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.TTS_SERVICE" />
  </intent>
</queries>
```